# CodeIgniter : Call to undefined function url()

Tags: codeigniter

I have a fatal error

```
Call to undefined function url()
```

But I have

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

I my autoload.php

I am pretty new to CI. In advance, sorry my lack of understanding

Comment: Here is the user guide for url helper please read http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html Doc's link here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

There is no error with it.

So if you calling your base url, then you have to use `base_url()` keyword.

And in `config/config.php` file

1. Base url should be empty
2. And index also should be empty

For example

If you use `<a>` tag lke this

```
<a href="root_folder_name/file_name
```

But now with Codeigniter MVC

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>controller_name/method_name
```

Comment: I just tried to use `<?php echo url('write something', 'test/write'); ?>`
Isn't it the thing to do ?

Comment: No you have to use `<?php echo base_url() ?>/test/write`